# I am trying to get a line space but do not want to use print() command

Tags: printing

Below is my code:

```
print("Enter your adress below\n")

street = input("Enter Street name: ")
suburb = input("Enter suburb name: ")
state = input("Enter state name: ")
postcode = int(input("Enter postcode: "))

print("\n")
print(street)
print(suburb)
print(state)
print(postcode)
```

It just taking an input of address and prints it.

As you can see I have a separate line to get a line space. How can I do it with out that code line and still have space when the final print is executed.

Comment: What language or technology are you using here. Please advice on the language of the source code above and edit your question for clarity. You still haven't highlighted the code line in question. Help others to help you with good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting like the following:

```
print("\n{:}\n{:}\n{:}\n{:}".format(street, suburb, state, postcode))
```

You can read about it in the following link:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this.

```
print('\n',street)
```